# Change All Values in HTMLDIVS if Inner Value is a Negative Number

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, sql

We have a PHP SQL Query that is returning an JSON Array of values which are being assigned to DIVS in the HTML.
The multiple returned values look something like this for the end result:

```
<div id = "tdiv"> -58 </div>
<div id = "tdiv2"> -85 </div>
<div id = "tdiv3"> 58 </div>
```

We are attempting to assign a red color to all DIV values that have a Negative number.

Any Ideas?

Thanks Guy

Comment: First tell me where are these values coming from? Please show your PHP code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `jQuery.filter` over `Attribute starts with` selector

```js
$('[id^=tdiv]').filter(function() {
  return this.textContent < 0;
}).css('color', 'red');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tdiv">-58</div>
<div id="tdiv2">-85</div>
<div id="tdiv3">58</div>
```

Comment: nice scripting @Rayon , i really appreciated.